# Set Cache directory for WebView2

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, webview2

I am using WebView2 in WPF control to host the new edge.

In my code, I want to cache the cookie and browser specific data to a cache directory. The cache location should be set in the CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions when creating the CoreWebView2Environment.

Is there any way we can achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google turned up [this](https://github.com/michael-russin/webview2-control/issues/3#issuecomment-575165429).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the user data folder in the [CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/dotnet/0-9-538/microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2environment#createasync) method. Its the second parameter and the other parameters may be null.

You can then have the WPF WebView use your CoreWebView2Environment to create its CoreWebView2 by calling the [WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#ensurecorewebview2async).

However, you must call EnsureCoreWebView2Async before you set the WebView2.Source property as setting that property implicitly causes initialization to begin with a default CoreWebView2Environment.

You can read more about WPF WebView2 control initialization in the [WebView2 documentation summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2#summary) section.

Comment: "You must call EnsureCoreWebView2Async before you set the WebView2.Source property", this point saved my time a lot. It becomes an issue when you set source property in the designer.

Comment: My WebView2 control is in DataTemplate which is loaded if user selects Edge as the browser. Even if I try to tap into Initialize event, Source property is set and I cannot update the UserData folder location. Could you kindly tell me how I can update the location in this case?

Answer (score 17):

I have made a WPF application using WebView2 that sets the cache directory to user appdata folder. Below is a snippet of the code from my application.

```
var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, _cacheFolderPath);
await kioskBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);

kioskBrowser.Source = new Uri(url);
```

You can find the rest of the code here
[KioskBrowser (GitHub)](https://github.com/mortenbrudvik/KioskBrowser)

Answer (score 10):

This works too:

```js
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER", "C:\MyDirectory\")
```